# How to get rid of double escape(\\) when using previous command

Tags: command-line, grep, redhat, gnome-terminal

I have RHEL 6.8 installed on my office system.
Whenever i try to escape a character in command line and try using it again next time it adds extra backspace.

```
:egrep -c "run \[0\]" fileA
:egrep -c "run \\[0\\]" fileA
:egrep -c "run \\\\[0\\\\]" fileA
```

It keeps adding extra backslashes. Any suggestions to avoid the extra escape characters?

Comment: what happens if you use `egrep -c 'run \[0\]' fileA` (using single quotes instead of double)

Comment: I get the results but say if I have to search something similar and I try to modify it from previous command it adds \\.